# How to wrapAll in each loop in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some html `div` like this:

```
<div class="mainClass class_1"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_1"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_2"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_2"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_2"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_2"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_3"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_3"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_3"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_4"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_4"></div>
```

I want to have something like that:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="mainClass class_1"></div>
  <div class="mainClass class_1"></div
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="mainClass class_2"></div>
   <div class="mainClass class_2"></div>
   <div class="mainClass class_2"></div>
   <div class="mainClass class_2"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="mainClass class_3"></div>
   <div class="mainClass class_3"></div>
   <div class="mainClass class_3"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="mainClass class_4"></div>
   <div class="mainClass class_4"></div>
</div>
```

How can I use each loop and `wrapAll` (or something else) to add this wrapper in in jQuery ?
I don't want to `wrapAll` manually for every class (class_1, class_2, class_3 ... ).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How are the unwrapped divs created in the first place? It's not advisable to fix this in a loop after the page has rendered, so maybe there's a way to fix it at the source.

Comment: This divs are render by CMS so I must to add this wrappers in JS (jQuery).

Comment: Doesn't the CMS offer a way to edit it's structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to extract the class which groups them like `class_1, class_2` etc. then in the each loop you can `.wrapAll()` them:

```js
$('.mainClass').each(function(i, div){
   var clazz = this.className.split(/\s/)[1];
   if(!$(this).parent().is('.wrapper')){
      $(`.${clazz}`).wrapAll($('<div/>',{ class: 'wrapper'}))
   }
})
```

```css
.wrapper{ background:yellow; margin:10px; padding:5px; }
.mainClass{ height: 20px; }
.class_1{ border:solid 1px purple; margin-bottom:10px;}
.class_2{ border:solid 1px orange; margin-bottom:10px;}
.class_3{ border:solid 1px green; margin-bottom:10px;}
.class_4{ border:solid 1px red; margin-bottom:10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainClass class_1"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_1"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_2"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_2"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_2"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_2"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_3"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_3"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_3"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_4"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_4"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery function `wrapAll` and wrapper every element with the same class, check the example bellow:

```js
$(".content > div").each(function() {
    $(".content > ." + this.className).wrapAll("<div class='wrapper' />");
});
```

```css
div:not(.content):not(.wrapper){
    height: 10px;
    background: #0fc0fc;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
<div class="class_1"></div>
<div class="class_1"></div>
<div class="class_2"></div>
<div class="class_2"></div>
<div class="class_2"></div>
<div class="class_2"></div>
<div class="class_3"></div>
<div class="class_3"></div>
<div class="class_3"></div>
<div class="class_4"></div>
<div class="class_4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi why not select all div's using jquery and use loop on them to get set them up accordingly.E.g.

```
<div class="mainClass class_1"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_1"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_2"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_2"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_2"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_2"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_3"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_3"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_3"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_4"></div>
<div class="mainClass class_4"></div>
```

now perform jquery operation

```
$cont = $('div');
var content1 = '<div class="wrapper"><div>';
$.each($cont, function(k,v) {
   if($(v).hasClass('class_1')){
        //content for div with class_1
   } else if($(v).hasClass('class_2')) {
       //content for div with class_2
   } else {
       //include rest content
   }
});
```

This is just a rough overview how you can create your custom format content
Hope it helps